# Android google map v2 MarkerOption visible property!! bug or not

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to add a marker to the map with **visibilty(false)**.
But when i try to set the visiblity of marker in the **markeroptions** in the marker option the marker is still visible on the map

```
marker = mGoogleMapObject.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(key)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.hotel_pin)).visible(false));
```

But this is not working properly..

and i have to set the value as

```
marker.setVisible(false);
```

why the visible property in marker option is not working...

Comment: As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819832/google-maps-android-api-v2-markeroptions-draggable-and-visible-methods it's an already reported bug.