# Google Maps Android API v2 - MarkerOptions draggable and visible methods

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm playing with the new Google Maps Android API (v2) released earlier this month and I was delighted to see a `MarkerOptions.draggable(boolean draggable)` method which I thought would create a draggable marker when passing in a `draggable` value of `true`. However, on trying it (i.e. adding a marker as such to the map), it doesn't seem to do anything.

The `MarkerOptions.visible(boolean visible)` method too, which I thought would hide the marker from view when passing in a `visible` value of `false`.

Anyone been able to get these methods to work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The latter issue is already in the [Google Bug Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4677).

The `draggable` method should work. Look at the provided Sample project. Maybe the drag starts after a longpress, like in the Sample project?

```
    // Creates a draggable marker. Long press to drag.
    mMelbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(MELBOURNE)
            .title("Melbourne")
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
            .draggable(true));
```

Comment: Thx, the default marker is draggable after you do a long press on it.

Comment: i want to knw why its taking so much time to drag the marker?